# Why does $watch in angular js cause console.log to output twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app>
    <!--Head-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Lesson 5 - ng-show & ng-hide</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body {
                font: 16px/1.5 Consolas;
                color: #222;
                margin: 5em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <!--Body-->
    <body>

        <div ng-controller="information">
            <!--Input-->
            <label for="name">
                Name:
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Your name here please" ng-model="name"/>
            </label>
            <br>
            <label>
                Hide?
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"/>
            </label>
            <!--Div that is hidden-->
            <div ng-hide="checked">
                Hidden Message here
                <br>
                Welcome {{ name || "user" }}!
            </div>

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular_1.0.7.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var information = function ($scope) {
                $scope.$watch(function () {
                    console.log($scope.name);
                });
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If your run, this and change the value inside of the `<input>` tag, then you will see that in the console window, the every single time you change the value, the value you changed it to, is output twice, as shown below:

[image]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Watches are called multiple times per [digest cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime):

> The $digest loop *keeps iterating* until the model stabilizes, which means that the $evalAsync queue is empty and the $watch list does not detect any changes.

When you type a character, Angular enters the digest loop (because Angular automatically added an event listener because you are using ng-model) and detects a change.  It then goes through the loop *again* to ensure there are no other changes.  It does this because if a $watch triggers, it might change some other watched property, which then needs to be detected so it's watch function can be executed.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to know. Thanks for linking to the docs as well.