# D3.js duplicating my data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a data visualisation for some student related data (sample record below) but when d3 renders it, it goes through the data twice and overwrites it, leaving only the results for the second time through only on the screen. I am using a row counter here to so I have a way to set the y coord of each rectangle based how many rectangles there are. And I think this has somehow messed things up a little. Any help on how to make it so the data does not get iterated through twice would be greatly appreciated.

Also, just in case it matters, this code is living within an angular.js directive.

Apologies if I am just doing something really silly here

```
// student records sample...
var studentData = [
{   
"studentID" : 1001,
"firstName" : "jill",
"lastName" : "smith",
"workLoadDifficulty" : 16,
"smileStartAngle" : -90,
"smileEndAngle" : 90,
},
{   
"studentID" : 1008,
"firstName" : "bob",
"lastName" : "smith",
"workLoadDifficulty" : 99,
"smileStartAngle" : 90,
"smileEndAngle" : -90,
}
];
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('learnerApp.directives')
.directive('d3Bars', ['d3', function(d3) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      data: "=",
      label: "@",
      onClick: "&"
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      var paddingForShape = 10;
      var rowCounter = -1;
      var height = 400;
      var width = 300;
      var svgContainer = d3.select(iElement[0])
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr('height', height);

      // on window resize, re-render d3 canvas
      window.onresize = function() {
        return scope.$apply();
      };
      scope.$watch(function(){
          return angular.element(window)[0].innerWidth;
        }, function(){
          return scope.render(scope.data);
        }
      );

      // watch for data changes and re-render
    scope.$watch('studentData', function(newVals, oldVals) {
        return scope.render(newVals);
      }, true); 

      // define render function
      scope.render = function(data){
        // remove all previous items before render
      svgContainer.selectAll("*").remove();

      var workLoadColor = d3.scale.category10()
            .domain([0,100])
            .range(['#02FA28', '#73FA87', '#C0FAC9','#FAE4C0', '#FAC775', '#FAA823','#FA9A00','#FA8288', '#FC4750', '#FA0511' ])


   var studentRects = svgContainer.selectAll('rect')
      .data(studentData, function(d) { 
        console.log(d.studentID);
        console.log('hello');
        return "keyVal" + d.studentID;
         })
      .enter()
        .append("rect");

      var studentRectAttributes = studentRects
                .attr("x", function(d,i) {
                    return ((i * 50) % width) + paddingForShape;
                })
                .attr("y", function(d,i) {
                    var value = ((i * 50) % width)
                    if (value === 0) {
                      rowCounter = rowCounter + 1;
                    }                    
                    var value = (rowCounter * 50);
                    console.log('Y Val: ', i);
                    console.log(value);
                    return value;
                })                   
                .attr("height", 30)
                .attr("width", 40)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                  return workLoadColor(d.workLoadDifficulty)
                });


      };
    }
  };
}]);
}());
```

Comment: See if you can isolate the problem better. There are too many moving parts to really be able to point to what is causing your visualization to not display properly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - this is my first stack question so a bit all over the place. Turned out it was the duplicate $watch thing. But that issue you mentioned with keys is something I have run into a few times and haven't really understood till now - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your selector to `var studentRects = svgContainer.selectAll('rect')` which will match the `<rect>` elements you are adding on `enter()`

** UPDATED **

Along with the key advice @Wex gave, I plopped the code in plunker and got it working.  You have an extra watch on your scope, removing it addresses the problem (you may want to revisit some of the d3 docs regarding enter/exit though):

```
  scope.$watch(function(){
      return angular.element(window)[0].innerWidth;
  }, function(){
      return scope.render(scope.data);
  });
```

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/z0MXkUVFNmMEGJAaz7dw?p=preview

Comment: Thanks but no luck I am afraid. I think its something to do with the enter() update() exit() thing in d3.js which I don't think I am understanding properly..but have updated code based on your suggestion as its probably better practice

Comment: I just noticed your edit about being in an angularjs directive.  That's most likely the issue.  Are you calling the d3 code in response to a $watch?  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001780/why-does-watch-in-angular-js-cause-console-log-to-output-twice

Comment: Newer versions of angular have a $watchCollection method which may help you out.

Comment: Oh how embarrasing, you are right, don't know how I managed that!!! thanks heaps. Its working!! Being my first question on stack overflow I can't seem to upvote yet, but sending good thoughts your way, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

If you're performing a data join twice, you need to specify a `key` so you don't overwrite the elements that are in your current selection. You may want to change your `studentRects` definition to:

```
var studentRects = svgContainer.selectAll('rect')
  .data(studentData, function(d) { return d.firstName + ' ' + d.lastName; });
studentRects.enter().append("rect");
```

See `selection.data([values[, key]])`

> If a key function is not specified, then the first datum in the specified array is assigned to the first element in the current selection, the second datum to the second selected element, and so on.

Comment: Assuming I understand your question correctly, and that you have two studentData arrays, you could also just concatenate your two arrays before displaying them - that way, you only have one data join.

Comment: I thought the problem was there was a single array and that d3 was going through the data twice (usually not a problem with d3, but because there's a `rowCounter` you'll notice.  Also, leaving the key function out would cause the new data to not render (b/c they would share the same index, right?)

Comment: @redmallard - I'm not sure how having a `rowCounter` would influence which elements were added to the `enter` selection.

Comment: wex - true.  not sure what I was thinking (maybe row counter just had a bad smell so I blamed it ;)).

Comment: Thanks -  I have updated to use a key and put this in the code above (now complete code with the angular stuff) but its still iterating more than it should...still not sure. Maybe the rowCounter thing Somehow? I am not sure so any other thoughts you have would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for the links to the docs also.